# When doing PostAsync why wait is not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In a WebApi project I do a Post to convert some file to another:

```
var post = client.PostAsync(requestUri, content);
post.Wait();
var result = post.Result;
```

The result will contain the converted file so is important for me that current Thread to wait for the response before going further and use the result.

Well, it seems that it goes further and of course, the result is not ready yet... Do I do anything wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've seen intermittent threading issues occur with the approach Cuong is recommending. Instead I suggest you use this approach:

```
var response = client
      .PostAsync(requestUri, content)
      .ContinueWith( responseTask => {
           var result = responseTask.Result;
           // .... continue with your logic ...
       });

response.Wait();
```

The [ContinueWith method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx) is designed to guarantee your code will run once the original task completes or aborts.

Comment: This, so far, is the most clever approach I've seen so far syncing awaitables from a non async context. +1 to you

Answer (score 8):

If you want to do synchronously, needless to call `Wait()`, just return Result directly, the `Result` property blocks the calling thread until the task finishes.

```
var response = client.PostAsync(requestUri, content).Result;
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

In here, the content of result is still not ready yet, you need to continue to get the content:

```
var responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
```